# How to find the role after logging in to bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I already have access to Google analytics provided by my client and the bigquery has been configured to the project. But i want to know if i can create jobs. How do i find the role assigned to my id ?

Answer (score 1):

> i want to know if i can create jobs

Below is simple way to get this:
Just open Web UI and try to switch to project of your interest

a.  If you do have it in the list of available projects – just select it and then run (just in case) some simple query (SELECT 1)
If it is run successfully - you can create jobs in this project (because any query is in reality a job)

b.  If it is not in the initial list – select “Display Project” and enter project of your interest and also check “Make this my current project” box. If result is successful – most likely you again lucky and can create jobs in this project (but still – run some  simple query to be 110% sure

> How do i find the role assigned to my id

This would be more involved – you will need to use respective IAM ([Google Identity and Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/)) APIs

For example you can use [testIamPermissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/testing-permissions)() API that allows you to test Cloud IAM permissions on a user for a resource. It takes the resource URL and a set of permissions as input parameters, and returns the set of permissions that the caller is allowed.

The permission you should look for is [bigquery.jobs.create](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions), but yo can pass to this API list of any permissions you want to check if you have